# How can I get the last modified ftp directory in Perl on Windows?

Tags: perl

By my @dir = $ftp->ls() i can get the list of all dir but witch one is latest how can i filter that one. I am using windows os and those dir is from FTP.

Thnaks

Comment: Give more context. This is not the way questions are asked on SO.

Comment: So you have a file listing, with one file/directory entry per element in the array @dir...yes?

The entries which have a "d" at the start of the description are directories

The timestamp is available as one of the elements also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a qucik and dirty hack for your carelessly worded question:

First:

Assuming you are using Net::FTP

you have to call

```
 $ftp->dir()
```

and not

```
$ftp->ls()
```

to get the long directory listing.

Then try this:

```
use feature "say";
use Net::FTP;
use Date::Parse;

    $ftp = Net::FTP->new("ftp", Debug => 0)
      or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@";

    $ftp->login("anonymous",'-anonymous@')
      or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;

    $ftp->cwd("/pub")
      or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;

    @dir = $ftp->dir()
      or die "ls()/dir() failed ", $ftp->message;
#map {say } @dir;

#Now parse the array of strings that dir() returned    
#magic numbers to find substring with modif-date
my $start = 44;
my $len = 10;
@dir = map {$_->[0]} sort {$b->[1] <=> $a->[1]} map {[$_, str2time(substr($_, $start, $len))] } grep {/^d/}  @dir;

$latest = $dir[0];
```

This will work only for directories with this format

```
drwxr-xr-x  17 root     other       4096 Apr 12  2010 software
```

but not with this (note:year missing)

```
drwxr-xr-x  36 root     root        4096 Nov 29 09:14 home
```

The code will also ignore symbolic links such as this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           8 May 30  2011 i -> incoming
```

but it will give you a start.

The

```
   map{} sort{} map {} @array;
```

construct is called a "Schwartzian transform", and does most of the work.

Answer (score 1):

The string returned by $ftp->dir can vary depending on the type of ftp server you are accessing.  The OS and user configs can also influence the format of the string so parsing this string is likely to lead to problems even though it seems to be a quick solution.  It is much easier to use $ftp->mdtm($file).  This returns the last modified date and time as epoch time.  Simple!